# Are isomorphisms coequalisers?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, category-theory

Given $\mathbf{Top}$ the category of topological spaces with continuous functions as morphisms, a coequaliser in $\mathbf{Top}$ consists of a quotient map, i.e open surjective continuous function.

In $\mathbf{Top}$ every homeomorphism (isomorphism) is a coequaliser for some parallel pair of morphisms.

My question is:
In an arbitrary category, are isomorphisms coequalisers for some pair of parallel morphisms?

My idea is that every coequaliser is epic and isomorphisms are epic, however I don't know how to prove if every isomorphism is a coequaliser.
Thanks for any hint or explanation.

Comment: Why do think that  quotient maps are open maps?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, isomorphisms are coequalizers in any category. Let $f: X \to Y$ be an isomorphism. I claim that it is the coequalizer of $(Id_X, Id_X)$, so taking the identity arrow on $X$ twice. Clearly $f Id_X = f Id_X$. The universal property is also easily verfied: any $h$ with this property (so that is really *any* $h: X \to Z$) we get $h f^{-1}: Y \to Z$ as the universal arrow.

Note that by duality every isomorphism is then also an equalizer.